# Would setting a mutex manually improve performance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, z3py, gil

My python program is definitely cpu bound but 40% to 55% of the time spent is performed in C code in the z3 solver (which doesn’t knows anything against the gil) where each single call to the C function (`z3_optimize_check`) take almost a minute to complete (so far the `parallel_enable` parameter still result in this function working in single thread mode and blocking the main thread).

I can’t use multiprocessing as z3_objects aren’t serializable friendly (except if someone here can prove otherwise). As they are several tasks (where each tasks adds more z3 work in a dict for other tasks), I initially set up mulithreading directly. But the Gil definitely hurts performance more than there is a benefit (especially with hyperthreading) despite the huge time spent in the solver.

But if I set up a blocking mutex manually (through `threading.Lock.aquire()`) in the z3py module just after the switch from C code which would allows an other thread running only if all other threads are performing solver work, would this remove the gil performance penalty (since their would be only 1 thread at time executing python code and it would always be the same one until the lock is released before `z3_optimize_check`)?
**I mean would using `threading.Lock.aquire()` triggers calls to `PyEval_SaveThread()` as if z3 was doing it directly?**

Answer (score 0):

> so far the `parallel_enable` parameter still result in this function working in single thread mode and blocking the main thread

I think you are misunderstanding that. z3 running in parallel mode means that you call it from a single Python thread, and then it spawns multiple OS-level threads for itself, doing the job, cleaning up the threads and returning the result for you. It does not miraculously enable Python running without GIL.
From the viewpoint of Python, it still does one thing at a time, and that one thing is making the call to z3. And it is holding GIL for the entire time. So if you see more than one CPU core/thread utilized while the calculation is running, that is the effect of parallel mode of z3, internally branching to multiple threads.

There is another thing, releasing GIL, like what blocking I/O operations do. It does not happen by magic, there is a call-pair for that:

> PyThreadState* **PyEval_SaveThread()**
>   Release the global interpreter lock (if it has been created) and reset the thread state to `NULL`, returning the previous thread state (which is not NULL). If the lock has been created, the current thread must have acquired it.
>
> void **PyEval_RestoreThread(PyThreadState *tstate)**
>   Acquire the global interpreter lock (if it has been created) and set the thread state to *tstate*, which must not be `NULL`. If the lock has been created, the current thread must not have acquired it, otherwise deadlock ensues.

These are C calls, so they are accessible for extension developers. When developers know that the code will run for a long time, without the need for accessing Python internals, `PyEval_SaveThread()` can be used, and then Python can proceed with other Python threads. And when the long whatever is done, the thread can re-introduce itself and apply for GIL using `PyEval_RestoreThread()`.
But, these things happen only if developers make them happen. And with z3 it might not be the case.

To provide a direct answer to your question: no, Python code can not release GIL and keep it released, as GIL is the lock what a Python thread has to hold when it proceeds. So whenever a Python "instruction" returns, GIL is held again.

---

Apparently somehow I managed to not include the link I wanted to, so they are on page https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock (and the linked paragraph discusses what I shortly summarized).

Z3 is open source (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3), and the source code does not contain neither `PyEval_SaveThread`, nor the wrapper-shortcut `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` character sequences.

---

But, it has a parallel Python example, btw. https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/python/parallel.py, with

> ```
> from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
> ```

So I would assume that it might be tested and working with `multiprocessing`.

Comment: `I think you are misunderstanding that. z3 running in parallel mode means that you call it from a single Python thread, and then it spawns multiple OS-level threads for itself` hemm no. But it might be all simply possible that `z3_optimize_check` supports it . And at best it spawn only own thread even if there are way more available cpu (and thus adding or removing more core doesn’t change program speed at all whereas cProfile which only profile the main thread clearly state that almost half of the time spent is done in `z3_optimize_check` with less than 40 calls per hours).

Comment: I’m also meaning: would using `threading.Lock.aquire()` triggers calls to `PyEval_SaveThread()`? internally as if z3 did it directly?

Comment: @user2284570 GIL can be released only when a Python "instruction" is under execution. When a Python thread steps to the next instruction it has to hold GIL again, that is how GIL is a lock. So while `thread.Lock.acquire()` likely releases GIL if it has to wait for the given `thread.Lock` object, it has to get GIL back prior to returning, so the given thread holds GIL when it proceeds.

Comment: Sorry, I still don’t understand… Would my idea allows multithreading without the performance penalty I got with the initial dumb implementation (since I’m modifying z3py directly there would be only 1 python instruction before switching back and to C code).

Comment: Downvoting. I’m not asking what z3 does or doesn’t: off topic answer.

Comment: @user2284570 a lock/mutex will not affect anything. The fact that the other threads are frozen shows that Python does not try to run them, all resources are given to z3. The things which may be worth pursuing are 1) z3 can be used with `multiprocessing`, see the very end of the post, 2) if you re-compile the native z3py wrapper for yourself, you can release GIL internally, 3) it can be checked under what circumstances z3 runs on multiple threads internally and see if the given task can be formed in such way that it will happen

Comment: Ok, thank you. But as far I’m aware, z3py uses ctypes. The example you gave is thread‑based not process‑based which give back the problem of serializing z3 objects. And even then I’m not sure that serializing a 10Gb large object each 10 second is a good idea performance‑wise. For the last question, the answer is simple : never ! In my case z3 doesn’t parallelize anything.